# How do I recursively walk a nested hash data structure?

Tags: perl, recursion, hash

I am stuck with what looks like a simple conceptual issue to me. After diligently looking for similar issues on the Web and Stack Overflow I could not find something similar, so I thought I could ask you.

I am building a **hash of hash** data structure which is deeply nested. The depth can be 10-20 a times. For the sake of this issue I am listing only till depth one.

I am unable to recursively walk through the sample hash below in Perl. I also have included my code.

It gives me the following error:

> Can't use string ("1") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at

Just so it is clear: my hash is bound to have certain keys with value 1. I cannot avoid them.

```
$VAR1 = {
    'Eukaryota' => {
        'Rhodophyta'         => {'count' => 5},
        'Alveolata'          => {'count' => 16},
        'stramenopiles'      => {'count' => 57},
        'count'              => 155,
        'Glaucocystophyceae' => {'count' => 1},
        'Cryptophyta'        => {'count' => 18},
        'Malawimonadidae'    => {'count' => 1},
        'Viridiplantae'      => {'count' => 57},
    },
    'Bacteria' => {
        'Cyanobacteria'       => {'count' => 1},
        'Actinobacteria'      => {'count' => 4},
        'count'               => 33,
        'Proteobacteria'      => {'count' => 25},
        'Deinococcus-Thermus' => {'count' => 2},
        'Firmicutes'          => {'count' => 1},
    },
};
```

Code to recursively walk this hash:

```
sub analyse_contig_tree_recursively {
    my $TAXA_TREE   = shift @_;
    my $contig_hash = shift @_;
    foreach (keys %{$TAXA_TREE}) {
        print "$_ \n";
        analyse_contig_tree_recursively($TAXA_LEVEL->{$_}, $contig_hash);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're calling `analyse_contig_tree_recursively` on (you're not using that `$contig_hash` parameter anywhere, and you haven't defined `$TAXA_LEVEL`: did you mean `$TAXA_TREE`?), but there's obviously a mismatch between your data structure layout and your recursive traversal pattern. Your traversal function assumes that all the entries are hashes, and treats empty hashes as the termination case: if `keys %{$TAXA_TREE}` is empty, there is no recursive call. Given your data, you need to test whether a value is a hash or not, and not recurse if you find it's not a hash.

```
sub analyse_contig_tree_recursively {
    my $TAXA_TREE           =   shift @_;
    foreach ( keys %{$TAXA_TREE} ){
        print "$_ \n";
        if (ref $TAXA_TREE->{$_} eq 'HASH') {
            analyse_contig_tree_recursively($TAXA_TREE->{$_});
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: or `Scalar::Util::reftype($TAXA_TREE->{$_}) eq 'HASH'`, if the data structure might contain blessed objects.

Comment: @Giles : Thanks a bunch. It dint strike to me that there are keys in my hash which dont point to hash reference and could signal the end of recursion. About the $TAXA_LEVEL, $contig_hash: those are just some of the other variables I use for processing. The main problem is clear now and my program works... You guys are quick and awesome.. Thanks a bunch

Comment: Man, you guys are fast. In case you simply want to see your structure and not necessarily do anything with it, use [Data::Dumper](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html). BTW, when you get into hashes of hashes or lists of hashes, or lists of hashes of lists, etc., it's time to start thinking about object oriented programming. Takes a few more minutes to setup, but can save you lot of heartache of debugging later on. I recommend it even for one shot deals.

Comment: @David : Thanks for your input. Are you talking about Perl OOPs ? If so I would love to see an example. I am not able to get how I would do the same using OOP in perl. I should admit I dont use a lot of OOP in perl besides Moose which has made it easy.

Comment: Yes, Perl OOP. I'd modify the structure. Make this a class of called "family" Each family contains two members: COUNT, and MEMBERS which is a hash containing "family" objects. A member function would list all MEMBERS. Then, you could recursively call this member function. I was working on that when Giles posted the answer.